# Asking a question and setting and answer discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am trying to make a random question everytime someone does the command `s!work` the only problem is I have tried mutiple times on this and either all the list gets sent or I get an error! Here is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def work(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    users = await get_bank_data()
    user = ctx.author
    def check(m):
        return m.author.id == ctx.author.id
    question = [
        (await ctx.send(file=discord.File('work1.png')), 'DARLING in the FRANXX'),
        (await ctx.send(file=discord.File('work2.png')), 'Trinity Seven')
    ]
    questions = shuffle(question)
    await ctx.send("What is the title name of this anime?")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await ctx.send(questions)
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if msg.content == answer:
        earnings = random.randrange(300, 500)
        await ctx.send(f"You did good! You got an earning of **{earnings}** coins!")
    else:
        earnings = random.randrange(0, 200)
        await ctx.send(f"Did you even try? You got **{earnings}** coins!")

    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        users = json.dump(users, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `question` list you are `send`ing both questions before you even do anything with the list, is this intended?

[random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) just rearranges the items in your `question` list, so you are just sending the whole list. You likely are looking for [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice).

Comment: Its not suppose to send both questions.

Comment: Anywhere you have `await ctx.send` It is going to send a message, so you are sending both questions in the instantiation of your `question` list

Comment: So do I just remove them?

Comment: I dunno man its your code, if you don't want it to send there then don't send it there

Comment: Also How do I extract the answer from the list?

Comment: random.choice as I said in my original answer

Comment: But if I do that how would the if command work in this situation?

Comment: You want to send a random question right, so have a list of questions, use random,choice to select a random item from that list, and do with it as you please

Comment: I tried doing what you told me but it got some errors and the image wouldn't display